# Given a linear transformation $T:V\to V,$ show that $B_n=\ker T^n, B_n\subseteq B_{n+1}$ and $B=\bigcup_i B_i$ is a subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Can someone explain why this is true and how to begin proving this fact?

Comment: Is $B_{n=1}$ supposed to be $B_{n-1}$?

Comment: Also, you might check if you really *want* $B_n \subseteq B_{n - 1}$ (it is easily shown to be false!).  Perhaps $B_{n - 1} \subseteq B_n$?  Cheers!

Comment: This time, it should be difficult to blame the instructor since, as the answer below shows, this only requires to *apply the definitions*.

Comment: @Did, I was just commenting on the situation in a different question. This is not even from "an instructor". But thanks for looking at all of my posts and commentating all over the place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $v\in \ker T^{n}$ then $T^{n+1}(v)=T(T^{n}(v))=T(0)=0$ so $v\in \ker T^{n+1}$,

$\therefore$ $B_{n}\subseteq B_{n+1}$

If $v,w\in B$ then there exist $m,n$ such that $v\in B_m$ and $w\in B_n$.

Let $k=\max(m,n)$. Then $v,w\in B_k$ which is a subspace because it is the kernel of a linear map and therefore, $v+w\in B_k\implies v+w\in B$.

Therefore, $B$ is a subspace.

Comment: @BrianO Thank you. It is getting late and my brain is not working.